# Where to add or place external Javascript files in angular cli project structure and use them in typescript file?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

In my angular cli project, I need to refer external js library which are not node packages. So, they will not be under node_modules folder as they are not installed by npm. These are loose js files.

1. In angular cli project structure, where should I add them as a best
   practice so that I can add them in scripts array in
   .angular-cli.json file?
2. How do I use them in my typescript file?

Below link explains how do we refer them in scripts array of .angular-cli.json file. However, it doesn't tell about where should external js files be added in folder structure of angular cli project if they are not node modules.
[Angular Cli Webpack, How to add or bundle external js files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38855891/angular-cli-webpack-how-to-add-or-bundle-external-js-files)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46014106/how-to-add-my-own-node-js-script-to-angular-4-project/46014372#46014372

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add your external js file inside the assets folder like : assets=>js=>filename.js

**.angular-cli.json**

```
"scripts": [
    "../src/assets/js/externalfilename.js"
]
```

important after changes in .angular-cli.json file. Stop the project then start

How its use in ts file example below :

**editor.js**

```
<!-- assets/js/editor.js -->
Editor = function() {
    //This is my javascript function
    console.log('Editor');
}
```

editor.js will add in .angular-cli.json

```
"scripts": [
        "../src/assets/js/editor.js"
    ]
```

in component.ts file

```
declare var Editor: any;

export class EditorComponent {

}
```

Comment: I've added one more question - How do I use them in my typescript file? Can you also please help?